# Logic to ensure a method is only called once

Tags: c#, idisposable

I'm writing an `IDisposable` class, which is intended to be used in a multi-threaded environment. I want to make sure `Dispose()` is only called once. So far I came up with:

```
int _isDisposingAsInt = 0;
public void Dispose()
{
    if (Interlocked.Exchange(ref _isDisposingAsInt , 1) == 0)
        return;        

    // Dispose code
    ....
}
```

Is there a more elegant way of achieving this?

**EDIT**
Important addition - I do not intend to call `Dispose()` from multiple threads. I intend to use `_isDisposingAsInt` to signal a background thread, which listens to a serial port, and may terminate ungracefully, that it should not re-throw an exception.

Comment: Calling IDisposable.Dispose from multiple threads would be an anti-pattern. Don't do this. Have one thread be the owner of the object. Orchestrate the flow of execution so that the owner thread ensures other threads finished using the object before the owner calls Dispose on it.

Comment: @sevatitov - you are correct - I've added some explanation on my intended use.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, declare _isDisposingAsInt  as volatile because you want it to get updated in all threads.

Secondly, you need to declare an object and lock it/exchange it's value in order to know you have been at the Dispose.
You did it in 1 line, there is no shorter than that.
You can do it in another efficient way:

```
if(Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _isDisposingAsInt , 1 , 0) == 0)
```

This way you check before the exchange if the value is 0, and u save some bus and blocking threads.

Comment: You don't need `volatile` here, the `Interlocked.CompareExchange()` is enough.